# How to create functions for navigating paths in unix (in tch shell)

Tags: function, unix

How to create functions for navigating paths in unix (in tch shell), below I have created is not working:

```
#!/bin/sh
proto(){
if [ $# == 2 ]
        then
                `cd /zz/apxxcd/$1/$2/aaaa/caaa/`
        else
                `cd /Vscm/nnnn/$1/saseng/aaa/`
fi
}

proto
```

Comment: You say in headline C shell, but in script you use Bourne shell. Can you clarify?

Comment: its C shell, can u correct me where u found out it as bourne shell.. i am new to this unix platform ,... if something is wrong in code can u correct it

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

1. Your `$#` has the bad comparision operator, it should be `-eq` not `==`
2. You don't give parameter to `proto` function when you call it.
   Change `proto` line to `proto $*`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
proto(){
if [ $# -eq 2 ]
        then
                `cd /zz/apxxcd/$1/$2/aaaa/caaa/`
        else
                `cd /Vscm/nnnn/$1/saseng/aaa/`
fi
}

proto $*
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu, not sure why still its not working!!!

Comment: i made changes as u suggested still not working